# mysql select 2 tables and order by 1 of them by date (more close to the current time)

Tags: php, mysql, date

This is my problem.

### table ns_leagues:

```
id   name
1    League 1
2    League 2
3    League 3
```

### table ns_upcoming:

```
upID   league   date
1      1        1410390000
2      2        1411990200
3      3        1412010000
```

I have this 2 columns and I want to select the leagues from table `ns_leagues` and order by the row from the `ns_upcoming` with the date more close to the current time.

I tried several ways but nothings is working so far.

FAIL:

```
SELECT id 
FROM ns_leagues 
WHERE id in (
    SELECT league 
    FROM ns_upcoming 
    WHERE date<='".$now."' 
    ORDER BY date ASC

SELECT DISTINCT id 
from ns_leagues a 
LEFT JOIN ns_upcoming v ON  a.id = v.league AND v.date<= '".$now."' 
ORDER BY v.date ASC
```

CURRENT:

```
SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."leagues ORDER BY id DESC
```

This is what I have right now (on the right side: PROXIMOS PARTIDOS): http://www.nuno-silva.pt/jobs/mark/index.php

"En vivo" means that date >= time(); and it's not finished.
The times are countdowns for the match.

I need to order the leagues by date (selecting for that the row with the closest date to time(); from column date of table ns_upcoming of the selected league)

Could you  give me a help on this one please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to sort by the time DIFFERENCE between "now" and the match's time, e.g.

```
SELECT ...
...
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(ns_upcoming.date, curdate())
```

Comment: well but that didnt solve it all because I want to select a row of ns_upcoming and order the leagues by the date of that row. ANd that row date must be close to the currenttime